# Specify dashboard port for dask

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

Is there a way to manually specify the port for the dashboard when creating a dask cluster using [dask-jobqueue](https://jobqueue.dask.org/en/latest/index.html)? When 8787 is taken, it randomly picks a different port, which means that one needs to set up a different tunneling every time.

```
from dask_jobqueue import PBSCluster
cluster = PBSCluster() # ideally here dashboard_port=
cluster.scale(10)         

from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client(cluster)  # Connect this local process to remote workers
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [dask-jobqueue docs](https://jobqueue.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask_jobqueue.PBSCluster.html#dask_jobqueue.PBSCluster), additional `kwargs` are passed to [`LocalCluster`](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/local-cluster.html#distributed.deploy.local.LocalCluster) so you should be able to pass the `dashboard_address` e.g.

```
cluster = PBSCluster(dashboard_address=':1234')
```

Have you tried that?

Comment: Note that this will still be ignored if the port is already taken.